# Why is my planning time consistently slower than execution time?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

On small tables with 5,000 rows I get:

```
SELECT category_id FROM widgets WHERE category_id = 1;
Index Only Scan using widgets_category_id on widgets  (cost=0.28..5.20 rows=26 width=8) (actual time=0.083..0.160 rows=70 loops=1)
Index Cond: (category_id = 1)
Heap Fetches: 7
Planning time: 2.758 ms
Execution time: 0.213 ms
```

and on large tables with 100m rows I get:

```
SELECT customer_id FROM orders WHERE customer_id = 1;
Index Only Scan using orders_customer_id on orders  (cost=0.58..1372.32 rows=65243 width=8) (actual time=0.155..0.402 rows=158 loops=1)
Index Cond: (customer_id = 1)
Heap Fetches: 109
Planning time: 16.019 ms
Execution time: 0.493 ms
```

This seems to be a consistent theme when running a bunch of different queries on different tables.

I'm using version 10.4 and my shared buffers is 64GB (25% of total RAM).

Comment: as more shared_buffers you have, as bigger chance to get pages directly from RAM. although I find it probably too fast half millisecond for index on million rows, even with such cardinality